# Can't obtain valid Facebook user_online_presence information

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

This used to work for me before, but some time ago I realised it doesn't work any more. I'm trying to run a FQL query for retrieving user_online_presence status (whether user is available for chat) on facebook. So, my query goes like this:

```
SELECT online_presence FROM user WHERE uid=userID
```

where userID is the actual user id on facebook.

But, regardless I'm online or offline on facebook, this query always gives me 'offline' status instead of 'active' (or 'idle').

To reproduce this on your own, simply go to the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/), obtain a token with permission user_online_presence, and type in the box:

```
fql?q=SELECT uid,online_presence FROM user WHERE  uid = me()
```

I would really appreciate if anybody can help me with this. Thanks!

Comment: I've reported this as a [bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/129383637170749) on Facebook and they have confirmed it's a bug.